# Appropriate technique to create new object by user on front end in Qt

Tags: qt, qml

I'm creating an app that uses `qml` in the front end to create a new object `onclicked`. Is the appropriate way to go about this is to create a `QOBJECT`  helper class that will solely serve to instantiate new objects of my other class?

Edit: I am wanting to create a C++ object from the front end with `qml`. I am **not creating a qml object**. So, if I click my button, C++ instantiates a new object. That is why I ask if I need to create a specialized `QOBJECT` class that has a `public signal` method solely to create new objects of my other class.

Or should I only have one class that can instantiate new objects of itself using a pointer?

Comment: Should the QML side be aware of the newly created C++ objets ? Who will own (QObject parent ?) the created objects ?

Comment: For this specific object, no, QML does not need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient solution is to employ a singleton. It will avoid to overhead of the factory object lookup, and it will not associate the created object with any particular state, which is known to play tricks with object lifetime.

Additionally, if you create the QML object from C++, you can avoid a fair amount of memory usage bloat. You can also have a C++ object as a singleton:

```
qmlRegisterSingletonType<YourSingleton>("Module", 1, 0, "Singleton", singletonFactoryCallback);
```

Comment: I added more details to my question. I don't believe a singleton is what I need.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you believe, especially when you lack knowledge and experience on the subject. A singleton is by far the most efficient solution. And it doesn't mater if you create C++ or QML objects, you can do either one or both. You create a `class Factory : public QObject {}` with say a `make()` function, you register it as a singleton, then you import and use it from QML.

Comment: Wow. Is it more efficient than a `QObject` registered as a context property` ? What if OP have a custom QML type written in c++ and needs to create objects from it, how a singleton will help ? To me the question is too vague in its current state to tell that a singleton is the most efficient solution.

Comment: Context properties take time to look up, and depending on how deep you are in the object tree, this lookup will have to traverse many contexts before it resolves the property. Also, if the property is shadowed by another of a similar name, you will never reach the one you are faster. Regardless of what you want to create, the singleton is the most efficient means to reference the factory object.

Comment: All the documentation I've read and all the Qt training videos I've watched never, ever mentioned using a singleton over a context property. You can see why that would be confusing.
@GrecKo What other details do you need? What am I missing in the question?

Comment: The two are very different, a singleton is always one single global object, the context property can be shadowed, it can change, and whatnot. The documentation also labels `QList` the "right class" for most purposes, but in reality it is almost always the least efficient choice. Much like context properties, it will do the trick, but it is not the best tool for the task most of the time.